# Quickblox REST API for System Notification

Tags: rest, quickblox

Copied from email.

I would like to know, is there a way to send System Message in REST API, which just like the iOS API.
I have tried "System Notifications" in the documents, but it returns error.

Below is my REST request sent to server. I logged in using the token before send this one.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "QB-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-d "chat_dialog_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&recipient_id=xxxxxxx&extraParams.moduleIdentifier=SystemNotifications&sys_msg_type=update_group&type=headline&send_to_chat=1" \
https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Message.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`extraParams.moduleIdentifier` - wrong name of parameter

You cannot use `.` in name of parameter

if you want to set custom parameter inside `extra_params` then you need to set parameter `moduleIdentifier` without `extraParams.`

Comment: This will make the message sent as normal message.
The purpose of this is to send SystemMessage / SystemNofications instead.
According to doc in quickblox:

There is a special channel for any system notifications. The end user can use it to split regular chat messages and other system events.
All such messages should contain extraParams.moduleIdentifier=SystemNotifications and use type=headline.