# How to send message of type System Notification in QuickBlox using PHP?

Tags: php, notifications, system, quickblox

How to send message of type System Notification in QuickBlox using PHP?
I am using following to build a system notification.

```
$data       = array(
                  'recipient_id'        =>  26046325,
                  'type'                => 'headline',                
                  'action'              => 'call',
                  'message'             => 'Hello ',        
                  'command'             => 'encrypted command',
                  'moduleIdentifier'    => 'SystemNotifications',               
                  );
```

but message is being delivered as normal chat message instead of system notification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683983/quickblox-rest-api-for-system-notification/37835030#37835030  - similar question got one answer but that's not satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

No way for now to do it via REST API

You only can do it via XMPP API